# Why does evaluatePreconditions don't work

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

The RESTful method code shown below, I want to use cache to give a quick response, but from the `request.evaluatePreconditions(tag);` I always get `null`.

```
@GET
@Path("e_tag")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response getItWithETag(@Context Request request) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder rb;
    CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
    cacheControl.setMaxAge(1200);
    EntityTag tag = new EntityTag(GOT_IT.hashCode() + "");
    rb = request.evaluatePreconditions(tag);
    if (rb != null) {
        return rb.cacheControl(cacheControl).tag(tag).build();
    } else {
        return Response.ok(GOT_IT).cacheControl(cacheControl).tag(tag).build();
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
@Test
public void testETag() throws InterruptedException {
    WebTarget webTarget = target("rest").path("e_tag");

    Response head = webTarget.request().get();
    System.out.println(head.getStatus() + "\t" + head.getEntityTag());
    Assert.assertEquals(200, head.getStatus());
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Response head1 = webTarget.request().get();
    System.out.println(head1.getStatus() + "\t" + head1.getEntityTag());
    Assert.assertEquals(304, head1.getStatus());
}
```

I cannot get the desired result.

Comment: You don't set the E-Tag on the second request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testing code missing If-None-Match in http head. The right way:

```
@Test
public void testETag() throws InterruptedException {
    WebTarget webTarget = target("rest").path("e_tag").queryParam("userId", "eric");

    Response head = webTarget.request().get();
    EntityTag eTag = head.getEntityTag();
    System.out.println(head.getStatus() + "\t" + eTag);
    Assert.assertEquals(200, head.getStatus());
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Response head1 = webTarget.request().header("If-None-Match", eTag).get();
    System.out.println(head1.getStatus() + "\t" + head1.getEntityTag());
    Assert.assertEquals(304, head1.getStatus());
}
```